# Accessing variables from a parent function within a jQuery click() event (Word add-in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js

The code for my add-in takes a search term, then displays a list of matching links on a table. Each link is supposed to insert itself into a word document when it's clicked, but I can't figure out how to pass variables in to a jQuery `.click()` function.

Currently, no matter what option I click, the URL of the link that gets inserted into the word document is always the URL of the last item on the list. So for example, if I had 3 results in the table: Facebook, Instagram and Yahoo, then whatever option I click, the URL that gets inserted is always http://www.yahoo.com

```js
function displayLinks() {

    // Empty pre-existing results
    $('#linksTable').empty();
    var filteredLinks = [];

    // Grab value from search box
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('linksSearchField').value;

    // Separate all links containing search term and put them in a filtered list
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLinks; i++) {
        if (sortedLinks[i].linkName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
            filteredLinks.push(sortedLinks[i]);
        }
    }

    // Get length of filtered links array
    var numberOfSearchResults = filteredLinks.length;

    // Populate table with loop
    if (searchTerm != '') {
        for (var x = 0; x < numberOfSearchResults; x++) {

            var table = document.getElementById('linksTable');
            var row = table.insertRow(x);
            var nameCell = row.insertCell(0);

            var linkName = filteredLinks[x].linkName;
            var linkNameFormattedForID = linkName.replace(/([ &/!*^%$#@+_-])+/g);
            var linkURL = filteredLinks[x].linkURL;

            // Add link to table
            nameCell.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" + linkNameFormattedForID + "'>" + linkName + "</a>";

            // Code to add link to word document
            $('#' + linkNameFormattedForID).click(linkName, function (linkName) {

                Word.run(function (context) {
                    const doc = context.document;
                    const originalRange = doc.getSelection();
                    originalRange.insertHtml("<a href='" + linkURL + "'>" + linkName.currentTarget.innerText + "</a>", "Start");
                    originalRange.insertText("Refer to ", "Start");
                    originalRange.load("text");
                    return context.sync()
                })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log("Error: " + error);
                        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I think I could maybe fix the problem by defining the `linkURL` variable within the click function itself, but the issue is that I can't access `filteredLinks[x]` inside of it. I *can* access the `filteredLinks` array on its own, but it can't read `x`, even though the click function is contained within the loop?

As a last-resort super hacky fix, I think I could just change the ID of each item to include it's URL, then extract it from `linkName.currentTarget.innerText`, but I'd rather not do that unless I really have to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh, the first argument to a traditional `click` function is the `event` object. 
Also, the jQuery docs show the first optional argument to the jQuery `.click()` as an `Object`. Try making it an object, not just a string
So, can you do this:

`$('selector').click({linkName: linkName}, function(event){...})`

Or, maybe this:

`$('selector').click(function(event, linkName){...})`

Although, it should be just plain accessible tbh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `var` in JavaScript is function scoped, and because the click event gets invoked **after** the for loop ends, the value of `x` will always be the **final** value of `x`. There's more information in pleanty of blog posts like this one: https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744

**The solution:**

**Use `let` or `const` instead of `var`**

**A slightly worse solution:**

wrap the contents of the for loop inside an IIFE

```
for (var x = 0; x < numberOfSearchResults; x++) {
  (function(x){
       ...
   })(x);
}
```